# Tab Focus not reflecting in Mozilla

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller

Tab Focus for following elements not working in Mozilla:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
                        <div>
                            <%: Html.TextBox(model => model.AddressLine1, new { maxLength = 30, style = "width:300px", tabindex = "0" })%>
                        </div>
<div class="editor-field">
                        <div>
                            <%: Html.TextBox(model => model.AddressLine2, new { maxLength = 30, style = "width:300px", tabindex = "0" })%>
                        </div>

<div class="editor-field">
                        <div>
                            <%: Html.TextBox(model => model.AddressLine3, new { maxLength = 30, style = "width:300px", tabindex = "0" })%>
                        </div>
```

My CSS is:

```
editor-field > div > input:focus
{
     outline: 1px dotted red !important;
}
```

May I know where I am wrong. Default Tab Navigation is not working in Mozilla Firefox. Working fine in Chrome and IE. Please assist me to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks Vaibhav for your reply.. but I have set my CSS like this:    editor-field > div > input:focus
{
     outline: 1px dotted red !important;
     -moz-user-focus: normal;
} but it is not working in mozilla.  How I can set my CSS??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery or Javascript to set focus like:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editor-field').first().children().children('input').focus();
});
```

Comment: Dude..Thanks for your reply. I have tried your solution, but its not working. What I want is focus should occur when I navigate Normally by Tab Key of the Keyboard.  Issue facing when I am using Firefox.Can you please assist me to fix by changing in CSS.Not much friendly with JS and Jquery??

Comment: I have also tried this link: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1034567 but no solution.

Comment: can you give me link of you page where you use it.

Comment: Sorry Dheeraj. I am unable to provide you that link.